# How will I save my credentials every loop in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, server, credentials

Is there a way in saving my credentials so it will not keep asking every loop? Like, isolating it outside the foreach loop. I tried removing `-credentials` and add it outside but it gives me an error of unauthorized access. I can't seem to figure it out. Sorry if this question seem to be stupid, I'm new to Powershell.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\servers.txt"

foreach($ServerName in $ServerList){

"$ServerName"
"=========="
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Computer $ServerName -Filter "LocalAccount='True'" -credential CORPORATE\usmenm03adm| Select Name

" "

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the credential outside the loop.
I edited your script  like below

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\servers.txt"

$cred=Get-Credential

foreach($ServerName in $ServerList){

"$ServerName"
"=========="
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Computer $ServerName -Filter "LocalAccount='True'" -credential $cred | Select Name

" "
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, read the credentials once with `Get-Credential` and store in a variable:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\servers.txt"
$MyCredential = Get-Credential -UserName "CORPORATE\usmenm03adm" -Message "Enter WMI credentials"

foreach ($ServerName in $ServerList) {

    "$ServerName"
    "=========="
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Computer $ServerName -Filter "LocalAccount='True'" -Credential $MyCredential | Select-Object Name

    " "
}
```

Comment: Strange downvote on this answer and upvote on a *similar* answer 1 minute later!? I have leveled them out. Let the community decide wich one is most helpfull.

Comment: I hope this communities igoal is to Share knowledge and help the fellow members!   Votes are next

Comment: @Venkatakrishnan - It is and it should but it was strange. Perhaps someone just disliked TesselatingHeckler's answer and liked yours better  but that should not result in a downvote.

Comment: Hi, I tested both answers and it seems that this answer still loops my credentials. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @KentMarionVG - Other than naming variables, both answers are identical?! I'm curious why this would not work for you?!

Comment: stumbled upon this, it was actually my downvote. eh, probably a missclick (no idea), I dont see why I would downvote this, amended it anyway